# Python APPCRASH mkl_core.dll error (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

While executing a Regression Model *python* stops working, I am using *spyder* and have installed-uninstalled *anaconda* several times.

Following is the error

> Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH   Application Name:    pythonw.exe
>   Application Version:  3.6.5150.1013   Application Timestamp:  5abd3212
>   Fault Module Name:    mkl_core.dll   Fault Module Version:    2018.0.2.1
>   Fault Module Timestamp:   5a6d0bd8   Exception Code:  c000001d
>   Exception Offset: 00000000037f2b63   OS Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1 
>   Locale ID:    2057   Additional Information 1:    856a   Additional
>   Information 2:    856afabdb44596b948f949971a9bb974   Additional
>   Information 3:    3bf8   Additional Information
>   4:    3bf8aad6cc25352af56a92972390ce43

Comment: What library are you using that causes this error? Scipy regression?

Comment: numpy and sklearn